# unable to access json array item without mapping or any list view react native

Tags: json, react-native, react-native-ios

{"top_menu":[{"id":1,"name":"Menu 1"},{"id":2,"name":"Menu 2"}],"left_menu":[{"id":1,"name":"Menu 1"},{"id":2,"name":"Menu 2"},{"id":3,"name":"Menu 3"}]}
I have above json array, parsed and set state using  `this.setState({ tabScreen: responseJson.top_menu });`

I unable to access array elements like  `{this.state.tabScreen[1].name}` while rendering text.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this,

```
{this.state.tabScreen['top_menu'][1].name}
```

Comment: :( It's  not working..same error evaluating 'this.state.tabScreen['top_menu'][1].name'